# optional const Vector2 - The constructor being called isn't a const constructor

Tags: dart

Unable to create an optional parameter in the following:

```
class BallState {
  final Vector2 position; 

  const BallState({
    this.position = const Vector2(0,0) // Error: The constructor being called isn't a const constructor
  });
```

And I dont want position variablke to be a Nullable:

```
  final Vector2? position;
```